# SQL Server Startup Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can i retrive the SQL Server startup parameter using SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [This](http://www.sqlps.com/blog/archive/2009/06/first-post-how-to-programatically-change-sql-server-startup-parameters-options/). It might help you.

The lines below is of your interest.

```
$startupParameters = $wmiserver.Services['MSSQLSERVER'].StartupParameters # YMMV on the service name if you use named instances
        $mtlSetting = $startupParameters.split(';') | ? { $_.StartsWith('-g'
```

You can use CLR Stored proc to use WMI. [Here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/07/wmi.html) is a tutorial.

Comment: i want to Retrive the SQL server Startup parameter.

Comment: The blogpost do the same first retriev then modify it. It is a WMI script so you need to convert it to your language of choice. If you want to read it into a SP, i don't know if it is possible.